# How many pixels viewing Form.Width size for FMX Android platform on different phone screens?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I am using Samsung Galaxy C9 Pro. My phone is 6.0 inches and 1080x1920 pixels.

Also, I am using Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo and FMX Android platform. (Master View)

My Form.With size is viewing 420 pixels and fixed for my all Form.Width sizes on my 6.0 inches phone screen size.

How many pixels viewing Form.Width size for FMX Android platform on different phone screen sizes? (Forexample, for smaller than 6.0 inches phone screen sizes)

Is Form.Width size 420 pixels and fixed for FMX Android platform on all phone screen sizes?

Best Regards.

Comment: Here you have the size of several phones http://screensiz.es/phone. A start would be this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101327/delphi-xe5-android-screen-resolution-device-profiles